# restful service without MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, action-mapping

I wanted to create a **Restful service** but when i tried the url "http..:8080/appanalytix-web/requirementservice/saverequirements" its not working

**Myservice :**

```
@Path("/requirementservice")
@Service("dimRequirementManager")
public class DimRequirementManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<DimRequirement, Long> implements DimRequirementManager {
    DimRequirementDao dimRequirementDao;

    @Autowired
    public DimRequirementManagerImpl(DimRequirementDao dimRequirementDao) {
        super(dimRequirementDao);
        this.dimRequirementDao = dimRequirementDao;
    }
    @PUT
    @Path("/saverequirements")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Override
    public void saveAllDimRequirements(List<DimRequirement> requirementList) {
        dimRequirementDao.saveAllDimRequirements(requirementList);

    }
}
```

Is it necessary to have a dispatcher servlet for using the url ? 
And as this is my service how will the client pass a json String using HTTP PUT or POST

**EDIT After adding servlet**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
         <param-value></param-value>  
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restServices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

i have added the servlet in web.xml and I tried the url http..:8080/appanalytix-web/restServices/requirementservice/saverequirements i am getting the following error

```
 ERROR [tomcat-http--17] Dispatcher.error(38) | Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [restServices/requirementservice/saverequirements] associated with context path [/appanalytix-web].
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [restServices/requirementservice/saverequirements] associated with context path [/appanalytix-web]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:534)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.vxl.appanalytix.webapp.filter.RequestAuthentication.doFilter(RequestAuthentication.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

Comment: Of course you need a servlet. What do you think would be mapping the `@Path` annotations?

Comment: with the help of despacher servlet, can i accsess the service from client?

Comment: so my URL will be http..:8080/project/Dispacher-servletURL/requirementservice/saverequirements

Comment: I recommend you try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a servlet, otherwise the `@Path` annotation does nothing.
In the `saveAllDimRequirements` method - you'll have to use put because you have the `@PUT` annotation.

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
   <param-value></param-value>  
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/restServices/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> i have added the servlet

Comment: what will be the exact url that i can use?

Comment: Most probably something like: `http://<server-ip>:8080/<project-name>/restServices/requirementservice/saverequirements`

Comment: If you're having problems I'd suggest you first change the `@PUT` to `@GET` and remove the `@Consumes("application/json")`. The browse to this url through the browser (with breakpoint in your code) and see if it arrives. If it does you can go back to `@PUT` and `application/json`

Comment: hi Avi, i still get the same error **Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [restServices/requirementservice/saverequirements] associated with context path [/appanalytix-web]**